# In RUP: What RUP roles are responsilbe for creating the Software Architecture Document?

Tags: documentation, process, roles, architecture

Based on the different views documented in SAD which RUP roles should should be responsible for creating the SAD? I thought from the beginning that the SAD was only for a technical audience but from what i can see in RUP it is more than that so it seems like it is not only the Software Architect that should be involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to RUP's documentation, it's the Software Architect.

Quoting the [Artifact:  Software Architecture Document](http://www.ts.mah.se/RUP/RationalUnifiedProcess/process/artifact/ar_sadoc.htm) online reference:

> ### Responsibility
>
> A **software architect** is responsible
>   for producing the **Software
>   Architecture Document**, which captures
>   the most important design decisions in
>   multiple architectural views.
>
> The **software architect** establishes the
>   overall structure for each
>   architectural view: the decomposition
>   of the view, the grouping of elements,
>   and the interfaces between these major
>   groupings. Therefore, in contrast with
>   the other roles, the **software
>   architect's** view is one of **breadth**, as
>   opposed to **depth**.
>
> The **software architect** is also
>   responsible for maintaining the
>   architectural integrity of the system
>   through the development process by:
>
> - Approving all changes to architecturally significant elements,
>     such as major interfaces, described in
>     the **Software Architecture Document**.
> - Being part of the "change-control board" decisions to resolve problems
>     that impact the software architecture.

Comment: Im not sure if it is clear in that definition but is the Software architect also responsible for creating the content of the document?

Comment: This is how I'd interpret "A software architect is responsible for producing the Software Architecture Document". But I guess this doesn't exclude contributions and/or delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

**Do not think "roles" as job titles...**

If you work in a traditonal enviroment, generally there is a guy who is job title is also "Software Architect"...If you work in an agile  enviroment generally you can not find a job title like "software architect" in team...So the important thing is who knows and who gives the important decisons about architecture: Who fills the role of the architect not title....

**In an healty enviromement[ traditional or agile] one guy can not give all decisons, so SAD is a workproduct of all team in practice because all teams  members sometimes play the role of "architect"...**